# Pretty URLs using .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, friendly-url

Everyone!

I have url like: `https://example.com/web/web/publications/11233123-21331-233256667`

How make this url:  `http://backend.example.com/web/web/publications/11233123-21331-233256667`

Thanks. Sorry I am relatively new to `.htaccess.`

Answer (score 0):

A simple .htaccess would look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ http://backend.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}
```